# How to convert point data collected at grid interval to a georeferenced dataset in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gdal

I have this dataset: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k06n9l05t25r6x2/newdata.csv?dl=0

(Sample)

```
"","row","col","flagrv"
"1",2361,530,2
"2",2378,531,2
"3",2360,531,2
"4",2355,531,2
"5",2363,532,2
"6",2359,532,2
"7",2368,533,2
"8",2367,533,2
"10",2359,533,2
```

And if I plot using this code:

```
gs.pal <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green","yellow","orange","red"),bias=1,space="rgb")
ggplot(data=ndata,aes(x=col,y=row,color=flagrv)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.01)+
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Scale",colours = gs.pal(5))+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(line = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = c(.93,.20),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#854440"))+
  ggsave("test.png",width=10, height=8,dpi=300)
```

We get this figure:
[image]

Now, the problem is I don't have Lat-Long values. I want to overlay the state boundaries but can't use the Maps package. Someone suggested I used gdal but I don't know how. Could you please tell me how I can map this into the Lat-Long domain so that I can easily manipulate it.

Edit:

I learnt from someone else that I can use this:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4269 FILE.asc FILE.tif
```

#

Errors for answers 1

```
Error: unexpected ']' in "spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, all_data[, c("flagrv"]"
```

Then I changed the code to:

```
spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, all_data[, c("flagrv")])
```

But now I have this error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : invalid class “SpatialPointsDataFrame” object: invalid object for slot "data" in class "SpatialPointsDataFrame": got class "integer", should be or extend class "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing at least the projection and datum of the dataset (but hopefully more info such as resolution and extent), there is no easy way to do this. If this is a derived map, try to find what was used to generate it. 
With this information you can then use the projection function in the raster package to define the projection of the dataset.

EDIT (based on additional info provided, there is a working solution):
Here is a working solution given that the lower left corner of the dataset has a 24.55, -130 coordinate, spacing among row/col is 0.01 degrees and projection is nad83. Note that the metadata info provided was wrong, as the min lat value was not 20 degrees but could be estimated from the southernmost point (key west) as 24.55.

```
#load dataset 
all_data=(read.csv('new_data.csv',header=T, stringsAsFactors=F))
res=0.01 #spacing of row and col coords pre-specified
#origin_col_row=c(0, 0) 
origin_lat_lon=c(24.55, -130) 
all_data$row=(all_data$row)*res+origin_lat_lon[1] 
all_data$col=(all_data$col)*res+origin_lat_lon[2]

#now that we have real lat/lon, we can just create a spatial dataframe
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
coords = cbind(all_data$col, all_data$row)
spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, data=all_data) #sp = SpatialPoints(coords)
proj4string(spdf) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4269")
```

r seems to choke trying to plot that many points, so to check if the answer made sense, I saved the dataset as a shapefile and plotted it on arcgis:

```
writeOGR(spdf,"D:/tmp_shapefile4.shp", "flagrv", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

[image]

I managed to plot it using ggplot2 with the code below, just be patient as it takes a while to plot it:

```
df=as.data.frame(spdf)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=col,y=row,color=flagrv))+ 
   geom_point(size = 0.01)+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')
```

[image]

Comment: I received this info: If it makes sense - gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4269 FILE.asc FILE.tif

Comment: That is good: it means that, based on http://spatialreference.org, the image has a NAD83 lat/lon projection.  The issue is that your X and Ys are obviously not lat/lon. I see no clear way of doing this without translating the row and col columns in your csv file into the equivalent lat lon values. If you did that, you could then turn your data into a spatial dataframe: check the points and coordinate sections in http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~rowlings/Teaching/UseR2012/cheatsheet.html

Comment: How can I convert the X/Ys into equivalent Lat-Longs? Could you help with some code. I am reading through that link. If I can do that, I can do the rest of the stuff, like overlaying state boundaries.

Comment: That is precisely the issue (not a code issue)- you need to know the extent in lat/lon of the original dataset. If that has been lost, the one way to do this is to find these values by looking at a coordinate of your extreme N S E W points in a NAD83 map. Based on the number of rows (for E/W) or columns (for N/S) you would get the info necessary to convert the current values into lat/lon values. Again, without recovering this extent info from a source file, I see no easy way around it (but I may be wrong).

Comment: Hi, I also have this information: 
ncols         7000
nrows         3500
xllcorner     -130
yllcorner     20
cellsize      0.01
NODATA_value  -9999

Comment: these values are precisely what you needed to do this. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error at first: Error: unexpected ']' in "spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, all_data[, c("flagrv"]"..............Then I changed the code to: spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, all_data[, c("flagrv")]).................But now I have this error: Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “SpatialPointsDataFrame” object: invalid object for slot "data" in class "SpatialPointsDataFrame": got class "integer", should be or extend class "data.frame"

Comment: I have added the errors to the question in case it is difficult to understand here.,...

Comment: Just tried it with the data you have in the top of the question and it worked, after changing the last 4 lines in the code. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, do you mind posting the figure you get? I am not getting it. :( Sorry. I am using the exact data and your code.

Also, I would like to use ggplot2 to plot which I have posted in my question.

Comment: I just fixed the answer to do exactly what was asked. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts. Can you tell me what's happening here? "all_data$col=(all_data$col-1)*res+origin_lat_lon2"

Comment: That is a regression to translate the row/col values into lat/lon. The origin_lat_lon specifies the equivalent lat lon for the first row and col (i.e., the intercept). The res argument is the spatial resolution in degrees of each cell, based on the info you found (-130 yllcorner 20 cellsize 0.01 ). Turns out the min lat val (20) was wrong, but I estimated it from looking at the lat value from key west, where the min row value seems to be located. I am glad I could be of help. Please assign this as the correct answer to your question, as this does what was asked and was not a trivial effort.

Comment: ABsolutely. Thank you. I got that part. But just one minor correction. PLease change that to origin_lat_lon[2]

Comment: Done! It was a fun problem to think about and has applicability to some of my work since it is quite frequent that I come across datasets that have lost georeferencing info...

Comment: Thanks. I am still understanding it. But it was really helpful. How did you find out about 24.55? Just a short answer will be fine. Thank you for spending your time on this.

Comment: The southernmost point had the row value of 0, meaning it was the latitude intercept for the dataset. By looking at the non georef map, I could roughly estimate that lower point was in Key West, so I derived that rough latitude intercept value from the map. If you need a precise georectification of this map, you would need to find the precise coordinate of that southernmost point. Now, one minor correction: I initially assumed that the row/ col values started at 1 (hence the all_data$col-1). Looking back, since the min row is 0, no such offset is necessary.

Comment: One last comment: if you eventually want to rasterize this dataset, (given the fixed interval among points), you can use rasterFromXYZ from the raster package with some minimal tweaking.

Comment: Hi Lucas , I have a big favor to ask of you. With my actual dataset, I am getting an inverted image. Can you please take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018107/how-can-i-plot-a-georeferenced-dataset-in-r

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply but I am all of late June and July in the field. I will try to see if I can look into your question, but do not have an r distro immediately available...