# How can I plot a georeferenced dataset in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, spatial

I have this gridded data that I want to plot on a US map: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9khcjgtv8ipo2u5/windspeed.txt?dl=0

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(maps)
options(max.print=5.5E5) 

all_data = read.table("windspeed.txt",header = TRUE)

res=0.01 #spacing of row and col coords pre-specified
origin_lat_lon=c(24.55, -130) 
all_data$row=(all_data$row)*res+origin_lat_lon[1] 
all_data$col=(all_data$col)*res+origin_lat_lon[2]
coords = cbind(all_data$col, all_data$row)
spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, data=all_data) #sp = SpatialPoints(coords)
proj4string(spdf) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4269") 

df=as.data.frame(spdf)
myPalette <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(10, "Spectral")))
usamap <- map_data("state")
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=col,y=row,color=m)) + 
  geom_polygon( data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point()+
  scale_colour_gradientn(name = "Wind",colours = myPalette(10), limits=c(0,1))+
  xlab('Longitude')+
  ylab('Latitude')+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(line = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = c(.93,.20),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#854440"))+
  ggsave("test.png",width=10, height=8,dpi=300)
```

But I am getting an inverted plot. Can you please help?

[image]

I previously got an answer for a similar dataset here: [How to convert point data collected at grid interval to a georeferenced dataset in r?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470895/how-to-convert-point-data-collected-at-grid-interval-to-a-georeferenced-dataset)

Comment: I guess in your previous example, the line #1 was the most northern latitude. In this case, it is the most southern latitude.

Comment: Thanks. How can I fix this? I still don't understand the original answer fully...

Comment: try with `origin_lat_lon=c(55.13, -130)` and `all_data$row=origin_lat_lon[1]-(all_data$row*res)`. **But** it doesn't totally match the border. You **really** need to check the boundaries of the dataset.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Do I have to add all_data$col=origin_lat_lon[2]-(all_data$col*res) as well? Also, I am getting this error: rror in `proj4string<-`(`*tmp*`, value = <S4 object of class "CRS">) : 
  Geographical CRS given to non-conformant data: -193.21

Comment: No, you don't have (did I say it?). Your x origin is not switched. For your dataset, what is the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your latitude values in this csv are reverted when compared to the dataset you previously had from the previous question you mentioned. All you have to do is to invert the row numbers in this new dataset:

Right after your line:

```
all_data = read.table("windspeed.txt",header = TRUE)
```

Invert the row numbers using:

```
max_row= max(all_data$row)
all_data$row=max_row-all_data$row
```

That should take care of it.